# Which software (Daw´s, Audio Editors, etc.) should be installed in Ubuntu Studio to work with videogame music and sounds?

Tags: ubuntu-studio

I make music and sounds for video games. 
Which software should I install on Ubuntu Studio for this purpose?

Comment: It depends on how you will create and manipulate the sounds and what format you will work in. Please edit your question to elaborate on such things.

Comment: I need some general tips about audio editors and DAWs.

In terms of format, it depends on specific work requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Linux Multi Media Studio](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/) is a must for every audio producer.

If you are familiar to MS Based Audio Tools, like: Fruity Loops Studio, Sony Acid, etc. You can feel happy with LMMS.

Screenshots from the official website at: http://lmms.sourceforge.net/screenshots.php posted here for your convenience:

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can create, use, edit samples from audio files, such as wav, mp3, midi, etc.

For audio capturing, manipulation, editing, DSP, etc. I can suggest you the [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), which is more like a multi-track waveform sound editor.

Screenshots from the official website at http://audacity.sourceforge.net/about/screenshots placed here for your convenience:

[image]

[image]

Additionally you may wish to give a try to the Israel Remix Team Multimedia 11.04 found at: http://www.israelremixteam.com, which features lots of useful audio/video tools which will make these tasks easy.

A screenshot of my System using the Israel Remix Team Distro posted here for your convenience:

[image]

*The left side monitor is showing the menu with Audacity and Ardour in the background, the right side monitor is showing LMMS with a new project.*

Your question seems not to be answered with a single one but this may be useful for you.

Good luck!

Comment: No mention of JACK? Is it not relevant here?

Comment: Not as far as I can say. I have made music starting from blank sound and never needed of Jack. Which gave me some problems in the past. That's why I choose not to use Jack but it is installed in advance in israel remix team, if you wish to use it.